# ¿Activar drivers PDO_OBDC para PHP?

Tags: php, pdo, xampp, ms-access, mdb

Hace rato sinceramente que yo no toco php. Ahora en la Universidad vamos a trabajar con placas Arduino y se quiere hacer un mini servidor con una pagina web alojada en ella.

Bien, como las cosas van a ser sencillas, he decidido utilizar Access... he estado haciendo unos ensayos en casa con notepad++ y **XAMPP**, pero al momento de intentar conectarme con mi base de datos en access, recibo el siguiente mensaje:

[image]

Ok, el mensaje es claro... no encuentra el driver. Lei por foros que lo que se debe hacer es habilitar la extension **php_pdo_obdc.php** en el archivo **php.ini** el cual se puede acceder facilmente apretando en config, en el panel de control de XXAMP. Bueno, el tema es que lo he añadido, pero aun sigue sin funcionar... no se si lo estoy escribiendo en un mal lugar del archivo o simplemente me falta hacer algo mas.

¿Como puedo instalarle el driver?

```
    try{    
        $bd = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)}; DBQ=$direccion; Pwd=contra;");
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Informacion del PHPInfo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACION**

Ha aprecido otra cosa distinta ahora:

> SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][Administrador de controladores ODBC] No se encuentra el nombre del origen de datos y no se especific� ning�n controlador predeterminado

```
<?php
try{
    $dbName = "webData.accdb";
    $bd = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)}; DBQ=".realpath($dbName)."; Pwd=arduiccess;");
}catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

No puedo usar esas DB con extenciones **.mdb**, como podeis notar.

Comment: Podrías mostrar el código con el que estás intentando conectarte? Los argumentos que le pasas al constructor de PDO

Comment: Listo @amenadiel

Comment: Podrías probar usando `Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}` en vez de `DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.accdb)}`?

Comment: Sale el mismo mensaje... @amenadiel

Comment: Y en la pantalla de PHPInfo, en la sección PDO, aparece listado odbc?

Comment: @amenadiel mira la actualizacion de la pregunta

Comment: Debería aparecer odbc junto a sqlite. Significa que tu XAMPP no trae el driver, o que no has reiniciado apache después de activarlo

Comment: Prueba algo como esto: `$bd = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=".realpath($dbName));`  En $dbName el nombre de tu DB. ¿Estás usando Windows?

Comment: Usando tu cadena me ha soltado otro error @A.Cedano, ahi te va en la actualizacion

Comment: Evita poner imágenes, mejor copia el mensaje (texto) y pégalo al editar. Desde móvil no se ve lo que dice. No me has dicho si estás usando Windows. Si es así creo que debes configurar tu fuente de datos en la configuración de Windows.

Comment: También puedes probar a poner la ruta completa de tu archivo mdb en lugar de $direccion

Comment: Con la ruta completa no sirve  tampoco, si uso windows y ya edite la pregunta citando el mensaje de error @A.Cedano

Comment: Debes agregar tu origen de datos en el Panel de control de Windows : https://support.office.com/es-es/article/Administrar-orígenes-de-datos-ODBC-B19F856B-5B9B-48C9-8B93-07484BFAB5A7

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano, ya me pongo a leer la guia...

Comment: Y yo insisto en que, sumado a todas las indicaciones de @A.Cedano te sigue faltando el driver pdo_odbc. Tienes que insistir en activarlo y reiniciar Apache hasta que aparezca en tu phpinfo.

Answer (score 1):

Debes habilitar la extensión PDO con el driver ODBC. En otras palabras, en php.ini debe existir la línea `extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll` y la DLL correspondiente debe existir en el directorio EXT de PHP. Después, reinicia Apache.

Una vez hecho esto, si haces `phpinfo()` y buscas la sección PDO. Debería decir:

```
PDO drivers: mysql, odbc
```

Hecho eso, puedes instanciar la base de datos (sugiero usar el formato de Access MDB en vez de ACCDB):

```
try {
    $dbName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "webData.mdb";
    $bd = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; DBQ=$dbName; Pwd=arduiccess;");
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Más info en el artículo de Sitepoint [Using an Access Database with PHP](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-an-access-database-with-php/)

Answer (score 1):

Comento aquí cómo lo resolví yo con CentOS 7. Mi problema era con la librería pdo_dblib pero la solución puede ser perfectamente aplicable a otras librerías.

Después de instalar php-pdo-dblib descubrí que tenía dos ubicaciones de PHP. Haciendo `locate php.ini` descubrí dos ubicaciones distintas, una de ellas parecía relacionada con el repositorio Remi.

Con el comando `php -i`  y con un fichero con la instrucción `phpinfo()` cargado en el navegador confirmé la ubicación del fichero `php.ini` que estaba realmente en uso.

Busqué la ubicación del fichero `pdo_dblib.so` y la ubicación del fichero `pdo.so`. La información de `phpinfo()` me decía que la librería PDO se estaba cargando correctamente así que copié la librería `pdo_dblib.so` en la ubicación en la que se encontraba `pdo.so` y luego busqué `locate pdo.ini` y `locate pdo_dblib.ini` y copié el fichero de la segunda búsqueda en la ubicación de la primera.

Con restart de Apache (httpd) conseguí que tanto por línea de comandos como por web me apareciera la librería cargada.